# How to serve (uploaded) images using Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this Meteor application in which it is possible to upload images. The uploading parts seem to work. I store the images in `.uploads`.  Now I would like to make these images accessable by the following URL

```
http://localhost:3000/uploads
```

After a bit of googling I was able to create the following server side code:

```
var fs = Meteor.require('fs');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice(0, 0, {
        route: '/uploads',
        handle: function (req, res, next) {

        var path = process.env.PWD + '/.' + req.originalUrl.substr(1);

        fs.readFile(path, {encoding: 'binary'}, function (err,data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'image/png'
            });
            //res.setEncoding("binary"); // this method does not exist
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
      }
   });
}
```

This code works, the `path` constructed is correct and in the browser I receive the `200` code, except it cannot display the image. Something is wrong with the data the browser receives. I checked the image on disk which is fine. So the code above must do something wrong with the data. Any suggestions what that might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I found after googling (and works for me) a few days ago when I wanted to do what you need to do 
files are in .screenshots directory mapped to :

```
http://localhost:3000/screenshots
```

code :

```
//directly serve screenshot files from /.screenshots dir
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var re = /^\/screenshots\/(.*)$/.exec(req.url);
    if (re !== null) {   // Only handle URLs that start with /screenshots/*
        var filePath = process.env.PWD + '/.screenshots/' + re[1];
        var data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, data);
        res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'image'
            });
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    } else {  // Other urls will have default behaviors
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: any particular reason why you're using `readFileSync` ? I just tried to get this to work with `readFile` (with the callback) but that doesn't work!

Comment: sorry, it was just a first test to serve screenshots, I ended up storing my (tiny) screenshots in mongodb, so I finally removed this code from my app. I think this is related to meteor using fiber, you need to use Meteor._wrapAsync to call async functions from meteor, maybe you should seach for _wrapAsync in StackOverflow for more information about this.